# Python-docx adding floating pictures

Tags: python

Python-docx currently doesn't support inserting floating images, but I found the following code to be able to insert a "behind text" floating image, which works well.

`````
from docx.oxml import parse_xml, register_element_cls
from docx.oxml.ns import nsdecls
from docx.oxml.shape import CT_Picture
from docx.oxml.xmlchemy import BaseOxmlElement, OneAndOnlyOne

class CT_Anchor(BaseOxmlElement):
    """
    ```` element, container for a floating image.
    """
    extent = OneAndOnlyOne('wp:extent')
    docPr = OneAndOnlyOne('wp:docPr')
    graphic = OneAndOnlyOne('a:graphic')

    @classmethod
    def new(cls, cx, cy, shape_id, pic, pos_x, pos_y):
        """
        Return a new ```` element populated with the values passed
        as parameters.
        """
        anchor = parse_xml(cls._anchor_xml(pos_x, pos_y))
        anchor.extent.cx = cx
        anchor.extent.cy = cy
        anchor.docPr.id = shape_id
        anchor.docPr.name = 'Picture %d' % shape_id
        anchor.graphic.graphicData.uri = (
            'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture'
        )
        anchor.graphic.graphicData._insert_pic(pic)
        return anchor

    @classmethod
    def new_pic_anchor(cls, shape_id, rId, filename, cx, cy, pos_x, pos_y):
        """
        Return a new `wp:anchor` element containing the `pic:pic` element
        specified by the argument values.
        """
        pic_id = 0  # Word doesn't seem to use this, but does not omit it
        pic = CT_Picture.new(pic_id, filename, rId, cx, cy)
        anchor = cls.new(cx, cy, shape_id, pic, pos_x, pos_y)
        anchor.graphic.graphicData._insert_pic(pic)
        return anchor

    @classmethod
    def _anchor_xml(cls, pos_x, pos_y):
        return (
            '
            '           behindDoc="1" locked="0" layoutInCell="1" allowOverlap="1" \n'
            '           %s>\n'
            '  \n'
            '  \n'
            '    %d\n'
            '  \n'
            '  \n'
            '    %d\n'
            '  \n'                    
            '  \n'
            '  \n'
            '  \n'
            '  \n'
            '    \n'
            '  \n'
            '  \n'
            '    \n'
            '  \n'
            '' % ( nsdecls('wp', 'a', 'pic', 'r'), int(pos_x), int(pos_y) )
        )


    def new_pic_anchor(part, image_descriptor, width, height, pos_x, pos_y):
        rId, image = part.get_or_add_image(image_descriptor)
        cx, cy = image.scaled_dimensions(width, height)
        shape_id, filename = part.next_id, image.filename    
        return CT_Anchor.new_pic_anchor(shape_id, rId, filename, cx, cy, pos_x, pos_y)


    def add_float_picture(p, image_path_or_stream, width=None, height=None, pos_x=0, pos_y=0):
        run = p.add_run()
        anchor = new_pic_anchor(run.part, image_path_or_stream, width, height, pos_x, pos_y)
        run._r.add_drawing(anchor)
`````

If I want to insert "Square Wrapping" image, how should I change my code? I found someone who suggested "changing wp:wrapNone/ to <wp:wrapSquare wrapText = "bothSides"/> will do the work for square text wrap." https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/159

I tried it, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please specify what "doesn't work" means.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson The picture is still a "behind text" floating image, not a ""square wrapping" style even after I changed these codes

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Do you have any insights on this?